# Self-answered question audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Another failed audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/12064428

Please remind, that the answers *cannot be seen* on audits. In this case, the question was answered by the poster himself. Indeed, the question as such can *only* be answered by the asker himself, since only he knows the purpose of it (which is revealed by the answer, not by the question alone).

This question should be removed from audits in my eyes.

Edit: Thanks for bringing up the duplicate. But I merely wanted to bring this unfortunate audit to attention, which really should be removed. (Btw. is there another (better) way than posting it here?)

Edit2: The question was elaborated in the meantime, the original was:

> Should I escape or cleanse user-provided passwords before I hash them and store them in my database?

Comment: The question in and of itself is really POB. Now the answer is fairly nice but the Q definately deserves to be closed (Maybe a historical lock?)

Comment: Seeking to improve the question as I thought it was quite clear http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321881/1011527

Comment: Would putting a notice that this is a self-answered question change anything?

Answer (score -3):

> In this case, the question was answered by the poster himself.

This is irrelevant, and in no way changes how you should be handling the question from /review.

> Indeed, the question as such can only be answered by the asker himself, since only he knows the purpose of it

It would seem that quite a few people disagree with you on this point, and feel that it *is* an answerable question, even by those that didn't write the question, but if that statement were to be correct, then the fact that the question is self-answered in no way remove those problems with the question.  At best it would mean that you could potentially edit the question into shape without needing to close it.

> This question should be removed from audits in my eyes.

None of the criticisms you've raised indicate any problems with the audit.  You simply disagree with all of the dozens of people that had evaluated the question up to that point.

Comment: As I said, maybe I would have voted to "leave open" if I had seen the whole situation. But in a CVR, you only see the question without answers and context. And taking this into account I think my close vote was not so absurd as you try to convey.

Comment: @Ctx The answers have *zero* bearing on whether or not the question should be open.  The context that you were missing is irrelevant to the decision.  If the question merits closure without the answer, it merits closure with the answer.

Comment: This isn't a straightforward audit so I disagree there.  See all the discussion on [this discussion about the same question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321881/why-would-my-question-be-considered-opinion-based-how-can-i-improve-the-questio?lq=1)

Comment: So does everyone here think that posting a self answer to a question makes it immune to closure?  Anyone care to support that position?

Comment: @Servy The whole contention of this dispute to the (known good) review audit is that it doesn't. The OP believes this question should have been closed.

Comment: @Magisch The OP is asserting that he wouldn't have voted to close the question if he would have seen that it was self answered, and he's upset that the review queue didn't show him the answer.

Comment: @Servy Please do not try to interpret something into my answers which I didn't say. To be completely clear: I think, if you get _only_ the question presented, it is reasonable to vote to close. Seeing the Q&A-pairs it makes more sense as a whole, since the intention of the question becomes more clear. This is what I said, nothing more or less. You already said that you do not agree with that, that's ok for me. The purpose of this was to remove this question from the _audits_, the audit system is imho ok in general.

Comment: @Ctx So you're saying that you would have voted to close it even if you had seen the answer?  If so, then why spend the whole question talking about self answered questions and complaining about the answer not being shown if seeing it wouldn't have changed your behavior?

Comment: @Servy I am very sorry when I do not express myself clear enough for you to understand. I will make a last attempt: The question and answer as a unit make sense. The reason for this is, that it is a self-answered question. The OP knew, what he intends to express, but that does not become clear from the question alone. This makes it a bad fit for an audit in my eyes. But the OP already tries to remedy this by rewording the question, this is a good solution I think.

Comment: @Ctx So you feel that the question doesn't merit closure when you're looking at the answer, and my summary of your question is correct, even though you've stated that I'm not interpreting it correctly?  In that case, see my answer; the existence of an answer, from the author or otherwise, has no bearing on whether or not the question should be closed.  If it merits closure without an answer, it merits closure with an answer.

Comment: @Servy You said, that I am upset that the answer is not presented on audits for example.You said, that I wouldn't have closed it if I had known that it is _self-answered_. Both is wrong. I tried to explain what I meant several times, if I still couldn't find the right words for you to understand, I probably never will. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Ctx If seeing the answer wouldn't have changed your action from the queue, and you don't have a problem with the fact that answers aren't shown from the queue, then why is the only thing you discuss in your question about why you failed the audit the fact that you didn't realize that there was an answer (that you're freely admitting wouldn't have changed your action and that you feel you don't need to see).  Are you saying that everything in your question other than the statement that you failed an audit and you think it was wrong is off topic and unrelated to the question?

Comment: @Servy As I said, I can't explain it any better, sorry. But out of curiousity: What would have been your verdict when you were confronted with the question `Should I escape or cleanse user-provided passwords before I hash them and store them in my database?` in the review?

Comment: @Ctx So you *do* feel that all of that information is just irrelevant?  If not, since you've said it wouldn't have changed what you would do, how *is* it relevant?  Why is it virtually all your question is discussing if you don't wish to discuss it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110402/discussion-between-ctx-and-servy).