# Why would my question be considered opinion-based? How can I improve the question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Recently I asked this question concerning [escaping passwords in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) and found this morning the question has been closed as primarily opinion based.

Why would that be so? The question is clear and the answer posted is thorough and definitive. Is there anything I can do to improve the question to get it reopened?

**EDIT** (duplicate question suggestion) This is not a duplicate question based on the duplicate provided because that Q&A asked about a POB question receiving lot's of downvotes which the question here did not receive. As a matter of course it received quite a number of up votes and a stellar number of views. It also did not ask how the question can be improved, which I am doing here.

**EDIT** improved the question as suggested by answers here.

<strike>**EDIT** Now, even after editing, it is closed again with 2 votes to reopen. please advise me on how to improve the question so that it may remain open.</strike>

Comment: *"Is there anything I can do to improve the question to get it reopened?"* - No, I thought it was rather well done. Being closed as primarily opinion-based means that those guys don't know anything on the subject.

Comment: I was one of the people that closed that question. It seems very short and broad to me, and the contradictory nature of the answers tell me it is indeed Primarily opinion based.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321870/self-answered-question-audit

Comment: Agreed. The term "should" does sometimes lend itself to leading a subjective question, BUT in this case there are quite a few reasons there is a clear cut answer (as evidenced by the good answer that you did indeed select). Should have never been closed.

Comment: I don't think it's POB. Just because answers say different things doesn't make it so, the key word being **primarily**. Answers can contain opinions, so long as they're based on logic and explained.

Comment: @patricksweeney That is a self-answered questions, and both upvoted answers directly contradict each other. That makes it POB in my book. Additionally, it is very unspecific and broad, to it could also be closed as too broad.

Comment: Honestly I closed it to to prevent it from being used as a bad audit as TXHX's link points out.

Comment: Why would it be considered a bad audit @ryanyuyu? And how can the question be improved?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Because the question without the self-answer is complete trash, not unlike the hundreds of one-liner questions we get here everyday. I agree the self answer makes it somewhat unworthy of outright deletion, but only just. Maybe a historic lock would be better.

Comment: @raynuyuy wouldn't a single vote to close have removed it from the audit pool?

Comment: @Magisch there is one of two answers to the question - how can that be considered too broad?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Both upvoted answers heavily contradict each other, indicating either that the correct solution is a matter of opinion (POB) or that the question is broad enough to allow 2 completly contradictory answers to be correct (too broad).

Comment: OK @Magisch - not my definition of "too broad" but I can see where you're coming form.

Comment: Wouldn't that question be a better fit for [security.se] in the first place?

Comment: per my reading [top voted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251878/839601) in dupe target addresses the issue you ask about. [Second top answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251876/839601) looks like a good fit too

Comment: And 3/5 people failed audits associated with the post.  Check [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36628418/timeline).  The post is clearly controversially on-topic.  Disagreement is fine, and I don't personally have any problem with it being reopened (people are entitled to that opinion).  But I thought it was POB/too-broad, and it was causing issues with the auditing system, so I closed it.

Comment: @Magisch the second answer has some dissenting comments and there is much to be argued about the second answer *but even I upvoted it* because it is due some consideration.

Comment: Let's keep in mind that the question was probably posed as a typical innocent one "comparison". One that Jay sees often from our peers here. Then Jay establised a canonical with a quality answer.

Comment: I don't think the proposed duplicate is a good candidate.  While some of the information on the target is relevant, it doesn't answer this question completely.  Specifically, the duplicate target fails to answer_why was this question closed_ and _how can I improve it_.

Comment: **"opinion based / too broad"** As long as a question can be answered based on facts and or references the question isn't opinion based. This doesn't mean that there can't be different answers, which may refer to different references. A question is then too broad when either there are too many possible answers, and right now there are 2 which isn't that many, or the question can't be answered within a few paragraphs (And remember that the limit for an answer is at 30,000 characters).

Comment: **"security.SE / SO"** The question in discussion is definitely about multiple topics such as UX, security and programming. For example the question ca be read as: "Is it good UX if you trim stuff like spaces at the end of passwords?", "Is there a security risk when I don't escape my passwords before I insert them?", ... So the question could probably be improved by going into more detail of the different aspects and ask about specific problems in that topic.

Comment: **Conclusion** Depending on how you read the question you could probably ask it on SO, UX.SE or security.SE. So improving the question and going into detail by asking about specific concerns/problems in the different topic can probably make the question more specific. It definitely isn't a  question which can be answered in one sentence, but if you write an answer based on facts which you can demonstrate it can probably be answered within a few paragraphs. (Also worth to mention at the end is probably that this question was written as a canonical)

Comment: @Rizier123 Unfortunately the question doesn't mention any contexts such as UX, security, or programming. It just asks if it should do X. If it mentioned such scopes then maybe it wouldn't be too broad.

Comment: @TylerH That is my point. Depending on how you read it you could probably ask the question on 3 different SE sites. So going into more detail can definitely break that question down and make it more specific / answerable.

Comment: @Rizier123 Generally if you have to span a comment over *three* comments to fit, you should probably just be posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe nobody even flagged any comment here, but more a moderator deleted all comments which aren't directly about this meta post here to keep the comments and with this the long discussion as small as possible. But not sure on that.

Comment: @Rizier123 the one I posted about deceze's variable scope Q&A, shouldn't have been deleted, it was worthy to **prove a point.**

Comment: @Fred-ii- I responded to your flag on why your comments were deleted.  These will probably be deleted too since they aren't about the meta post.  If you want to raise a separate question, you can; but I can save you some time: Comments are ephemeral and subject to deletion for any reason. Want your point of view to stick around? Post it as an answer.  Edit: Looks like another mod responded to your flag before I did. So I'll do a 'what they said' in their response.

Comment: @animuson Yes you are probably right and I get your point. But I'm not an eloquent person at all so I'm just hiding my 2 cents in the comments.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Point taken George, and thanks for giving me a straight answer.

Comment: @TylerH thanks for your grammatical changes! Appreciated!

Comment: @JayBlanchard np; on that note, are 'cleansing' and 'escaping' mutually exclusive?

Comment: @TylerH some say *toe-may-to* and some say *toe-mah-to* on that in PHP-land. 'Cleansing' is a general term which includes possibly 'escaping'.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Got it. I'd also recommend some other example questions the canonical intends to cover, like "Is cleansing a password compatible with hashing?" or "Can I escape a password I plan on hashing?" etc. (not that those specific examples are good ones...)

Comment: @TylerH thanks, I'll look into to ways to add more value to the question.

Comment: The question and answer should be a wiki, if you're intending to drive traffic to your own question and answer via the dupehammer.

Comment: @Will Did you mean more like: *"The question and **answers** should be a wiki"* in plural form. I'm sure Jay isn't doing this for rep points and others shouldn't be benefiting on it neither; it's only fair.

Comment: @Will why should the question and answer (which answer? There were [and still are] multiple at the time of your comment) be marked as wiki posts?

Comment: @Will So for ethical reasons, then. Is there some meta consensus you can link to that discusses this subject?

Comment: @TylerH I'd have to do what you'd have to do--search meta.  Or consult your own personal compass?  Anyhow, I don't have anything more to add here, so I bid you a good day, sir.

Comment: @Will Well, you said it *should* without providing any reason why or any consensus to back it, implying that it's simply known. If you think it should, that's fine, but it would be more clear if you indicate that it's an opinion. Otherwise if you're referencing previous meta community consensus, you should link to relevant discussions, to support your claim.

Comment: @Will Well, you edited it in after I had replied, to be fair :-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard - your opinion on the defintion of too broad is not important, it is spelled out very clearly *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.* The answers prove out the official definition, this is too broad. This is fundamentally a [Best Practices](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic) question in disguise as well.

Comment: Thank you for registering the lack of importance of my opinion @JarrodRoberson, much appreciated. I know quite well what the definition is as I use that close reason several times a day. "Too many possible" is not equal to two. Quite frankly most developers do not take the second answer to be about cleansing as it is about *manipulation* of particular characters within the password string. This whole thing has triggered some very strong responses though, so I am seeking ways to make the question better with negating the second answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - the *strong responses* is a very clear indicator of **opinion based** as well, so that close reason was not as wrong as everyone is making it out to be.

Comment: This is just the standard nonsensical hate several empowered users want to thrust upon members of Stackoverflow. People enjoy being bullies and want to silence others as opposed to doing the hardwork of actually having a dialog to solve the problem.

Comment: The answer really makes the question and proves that it isn't opinion-based... however you've accepted the wrong answer.  The one relying on a peer-reviewed RFC (which specifically addresses passwords and your exact question) collecting the wisdom of many experts is much better than the one posted by one semi-expert who has completely overlooked some major issues related to extended characters.

Comment: The answer was accepted prior to the second answer being added (which I upvoted as well) @BenVoigt. Doesn't matter, question was just closed again and makes me want to cease efforts to be helpful on StackOverlfow. Given that my question here riled up so many over *other* issues it almost seems not worth the effort. I expect that delete votes will start to roll in and the work will be all for naught. All of this even as the answer continues to receive upvotes.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: I hadn't noticed that was a self-answer.  The standards are higher for using a self-answer to "share your wisdom" and I don't think those are meant.  It's confusing -- why say "The act of hashing a password is the act of cleansing the password" when what you mean is "The result of hashing a password is safe to store in a database and doesn't require additional cleansing.  And the hash function doesn't give special meaning to any bytes, so no cleansing of its input is required for security reasons."

Comment: Because I am sometimes at a lack for words @BenVoigt. May I use what you have said here to make clarifications?

Comment: @Jay: Go right ahead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there anything I can do to improve the question to get it reopened?

The Meta effect has already taken care of getting the question reopened, but isn't the recommended way for all users to take.

It appears to me that there was some intent behind this particular Q & A that is not expressed *in the question itself*, although it's hinted at in the timing of the self-answer. I think [Drew](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321881/why-would-my-question-be-considered-opinion-based-how-can-i-improve-the-questio#comment337803_321881) perceived this correctly:

> ...the question was probably posed as a typical innocent one "comparison". One that Jay sees often from our peers here. Then Jay established a canonical with a quality answer.

Here's where the question could be improved. If you are creating a Q & A as an intended canonical that is expected to answer a question that is either frequently posed by new users or as a convenient sidebar advice piece, then you could say so in the question. For example:

> When considering hashing and persisting users passwords, developers may also think of treating passwords as they would other input data. This question is intended to provide a canonical answer for questions like this:
>
> Should I escape or cleanse user-provided passwords before I hash them and store them in my database?

That way, it looks like the question that a new user might pose, but with context to explain it.

Comment: Whilst I agree that some context is better, the question remains the same and is still POB in your suggestion (and the original question as the OP more-or-less copied your text).

Comment: I have edited my original question based on what you have said here. Thank you for providing the suggestions!

Comment: @Adriaan I'm not sure how to address the breadth of the core question, rather I'm suggesting that it's possible to frame it in such a way that it is irrelevant.

Comment: I have added some of the other suggestions I have found here along with yours @Mogsdad. Based on some other suggestions I'll be looking for ways to add value to the question and will be updating it more.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. I have covered that in some of the linked posts. Does it need to be more obvious?

Comment: I would drop a caveat statement close and underneath your two references in the answer that suggest "60". People often skim then fly off to their Create Table statement

Comment: You should not be including meta commentary in a question.  A question is where you ask a question, not where you explain why you're asking a question.  If you want to make a good canonical question you should be just asking that question well, there is no need to say that you're writing a canonical version of the question, and stating that you intend to in no way changes the quality standards for a question.

Comment: 10-4 @Servy, was going on a recommendation that had been posted here, but has since been deleted.

Answer (score 20):

Questions that usually start with *Should I do X* are frowned upon by the SO community because in my opinion they ask ***whether I should be doing something*** rather than ***how should I do something***.

In your question, you ask whether you should be cleansing user passwords. We can have at least 3 types of answers here :

> 1. Some people might say that cleansing would be better
> 2. Some might disagree with option-1.
> 3. Some people might say do X before cleansing Or don't cleanse if you are doing Y Or do-this-do-that.

And we will end up with lots of comments <strike>mod flags</strike> flying around needlessly. All 3 answers are correct in one or the other way.

Think about it, how is your question different from *Should I use ArrayList over HashSet?*. Without proper context around the question, we can **always end up with contradicting answers which are NOT wrong**.

If your question had started with *how should I cleanse passwords...*, then it would (perhaps) have been a completely different story.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for pointing that out! I'll make some changes to the question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Just make sure that it doesn't move from *POB* -> *Too Broad* :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Respectfully, it's already there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Also make sure that you don't invalidate existing answers by fundamentally changing the question.

Comment: I agree here. That was the reason I VTCed it as Primarily Opinion Based. Just a side note: a one-line question without code is usually not received well. Not even a whole lot of rep to back it will prevent that, especially with robo reviewers around in the queue who just see that sole line of text.

Comment: I have now made it a "how should I" question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestons @TheLostMind, I have used your suggestion and will continue to seek ways to add value to the question.

Comment: ***Should*** is literally the most important question in engineering

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Magisch and the previous POB close reason, I think the question is way too broad.

"Should I escape/cleanse passwords?" lacks any kind of specific context. What is your concern about uncleansed passwords? What is the problem you're trying to solve/avoid? This question belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com but not here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I was one of the people who closed this question. Its important to note that I didn't downvote it or either of the answers, as I think they're both decent.

There are two main issues with your post:

- It is very short and unspecific. It heavily looks like the dime-a-dozen one liner questions we get daily in masses. That alone is not enough to condemn it, but its a red flag. It came to my attention at all because it was a [controversial "known good" audit in the close vote queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321870/self-answered-question-audit)
- Both answers (heavily upvoted) contradict each other directly. This means one of two things:

  1. The question is broad enough that two completely contradictory correct answers are possible.
  2. The answer to such a question is primarily based on user opinion rather then fact.

Both of which are valid close reasons.  I agree that it shouldn't quite be deleted, so maybe a historical lock would be better? The answers to this would probably be a great fit for the Information Security SE, so consider posting that there maybe.

As to improving it, I don't think it can be. Questions like "Should I do X?" with no further context or specific problem scenario are very rarely on topic here.

Comment: On further review I don't see the second answer as contradictory, rather the poster seems to be adding to what I said.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Your answer says "You shouldn't sanitize the password input, here is 5 reasons why not" The second answer says "You should sanitize password input based on this standard, here's why" thats contradictory IMO.

Comment: That's why I'm curious about who's right there, and why I believe posting the question on [security.se] would get us the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The close reason states (emphasis mine, to show where I don't think it fits):

> Many **good questions generate some degree of opinion** based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be **almost entirely** based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

The answers given aren't "almost entirely" just opinions. To state that they are is, bluntly, ridiculous. They're based on references, facts, and  specific expertise. I also disagree with suggestions that the question is too broad, the scope that you've added with you edit was already largely implied with the tags.

I think some people were reacting quickly to a meta post about a bad audit (and I can agree, it's not really obvious enough for the audits; and just from it's length looks a lot like what a reviewer would expect to be a known-bad question), or were called to arms in a chat room.

The question is alarmingly short, which is usually an alarm sign for a bad question. On first reading, it may look too broad. But, in context with the tags, it's simply that you've asked a direct question; without any of the preamble that most questions would have to attract an answer of that detail.

Some people just seem determined that it's off topic, and, since it's a PHP question, I can't really disagree too much.

Comment: Before we start accusing certain chat rooms of posse or mob behavior, maybe we should find some evidence that that happened. Leaning on the crutch of "blame SOCVR for close reasons we don't like" is really harmful to the community, even if you're just insinuating it rather than outright saying it.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not blaming anyone. Try not to feel persecuted. Do you deny people were driven to that post from the meta post about the audit, and the post made in your chat room?

Comment: I don't know anything about a bad audit meta post; I came upon this one organically, and I've been in that chat room all morning. You may not think you're blaming someone, but it's pretty clear finger-pointing even when you make the supposition that "people were called to arms in a chat room". Even if it's true that people landed here from a chatroom, language like that is divisive and doesn't elicit constructive discussions.

Comment: @TylerH There was an explicit "please close this" message in a chat room. That's undeniable. There was also a meta post (linked to in the first batch of comments under this question) today. To try and deny that these two things contributed to the question being closed is ridiculous. You're taking half a sentence of my answer, spinning it to meet your persecution complex, and posting comments saying people are being harmful to the community. I blamed no one; I pointed out why the question got the attention it did from the two highest profile sources that matter.

Comment: I haven't denied anything, please don't make stuff up. Can you link to that CV message in that chatroom? And also I'm not saying "people are being harmful to the community", I'm saying that your one half of a sentence is harmful to the community. I said what I meant, not something else. Your aggrandizement is untrue, misleading, and not constructive, not to mention offensive.

Comment: @TylerH Saying "I've been in the room all morning", and demanding [evidence](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=30195019#30195019) for something when you could surely find it yourself, well, I took it as denying -- sorry. That was a misunderstanding on my part. But, my sentence is factually correct. If the behaviour it describes is harmful (and I don't claim it is, SOVCR performs a valuable service, and were it not for obvious personality clashes with y'all I'd probably want to be part of it if I ever got to 3k rep), that's not on me...

Comment: ... That the attention Jay's post received was that lead to this post, was the result of a meta post and a chat comment, though, that is not deniable by a reasonable person.

Comment: The burden of proof always lies with the one making the claim. It's not at all unreasonable to expect you to evidence something when you're one saying it happened. I didn't see it happen, and I'm assuming you did, since you're claiming it happened. Therefore it'd be less work for you to find the link than for me to look for it (you knew when it was posted, what it looked like, etc.). That's the reason I asked you to provide the link.

Comment: On another note, it's dangerous to say that those two factors are the undeniable cause, unless you can see referral traffic, which I doubt. :-)

Comment: Oh, burden of proof. Yeh, because that takes precedence over common sense every freaking time. :)

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed you edited you comment to include calling my post offensive. Well... that's interesting. I though we were all acting in good faith here. Clearly not.

Comment: I didn't call your post offensive. I called your aggrandizing comments offensive, specifically that you were attributing a persecution complex to me and putting words in my mouth. I'll repeat my request that you not make things up :-) I've acted in good faith the entire time.

Comment: And I'll introduce a request that you do the same.

Comment: What have I made up? So far you've only misrepresented what I've said nearly half a dozen times and most of my comments have been attempts to help you understand what it is I really said.

Comment: You said: `Leaning on the crutch of "blame SOCVR for close reasons we don't like" is really harmful to the community` -- when I did absolutely nothing of the sort, I simply deduced from the available information why the post had been closed.

Comment: Without providing any kind of evidence to support your accusation, that's a reasonable comment to make. I'm immensely confused, by the way, as to how you consider taking offense to something as no longer acting in good faith. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I said it happened. What more evidence does there need to be?

Comment: Okay, well, you have 10 accounts that all upvote your questions and answers. I said it happened, so I don't need any evidence for it to be considered true, do I?

Comment: But, in this case I am correct. And you are not. The evidence is easily accessible for both claims. Your confrontational attitude demanding evidence when it would be easy for you to retrieve it yourself, and you assuming I "misrepresented" what you said rather than misunderstanding it when I gave you the benefit of the doubt shows me that you're not discussing in good faith, but simply being argumentative for fun.

Comment: Anyway, that doesn't change that you put words in my mouth; before I put them in yours.

Comment: Actually the evidence is not easily accessible for both claims, but your tenuous grasp of logical concepts is an issue for another time. You're right in that I suggested you were pointing the finger at a particular chatroom, but that's not me putting words in the mouth, it's revealing the words you had in mind. That's a far cry from you claiming I said things that were totally different from what I actually said. It's not confrontational to expect evidence to support an accusation, in fact it's confrontational of *you* to make the accusation in the first place.

Comment: That chat transcript is public. The meta post is public. My reputation history is public. Where does the difficulty lie?

Comment: If you see a link posted in a chatroom and think it is the reason for an increase in traffic, that's fine, and you can even posit that as you've done, but *share the link without hesitation* to support your bold claim! If you had done that and framed your notion better, the discussion could've taken a totally different track of whether there's a causal link rather than me trying to explain to you what evidence is and why it's important.

Comment: The difficultly lies in that user account emails and IPs are *not* public, so the claim that you have 10 accounts is not easy to prove or disprove for us. It would require a Stack Overflow employee. Also, voting history is not public.

Comment: Then focus on the second part, the upvotes. How many of my posts have a score of ten? I'd be surprised if it's more than one (edit: I'm surprised, it's two). And I didn't "blame" anyone for anything, I was simply stating the obvious reason the post had been closed after weeks of no activity. It's not a "bold claim" when it's not particularly unusual for cv-pls requests to be posted in that room.

Comment: I didn't say each account had to upvote all of your content. A crafty person would only use them sparingly and in rotation to avoid detection, of course! And yes, accusing someone of something is always a bold claim, due to human nature of being social creatures and therefore generally non-confrontational at the risk of alienating themselves from their community if found to be wrong, etc.

Comment: Then I apologise to Ctz for the totally founded "accusation" that they made a [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321870/self-answered-question-audit) about their failed audit. I hope they can forgive my faux pas but I imagine (not putting words in their mouth, simply an assumption) that they just don't care.

Comment: That's not the accusation to which I've been referring. Have you mixed up this discussion with another? I've been talking about your accusation of a call to arms in a chat room this whole time... I've even clarified that already.

Comment: I know. I apologised to who I felt might deserve it. But, No. The "accusations" were linked, one and the same. They weren't even accusations (I never claimed or suggested that someone had done something wrong), simply a statement as to what happened. Again, I'm bored of this. It's been fun though. Have a nice day.